# SQL - how to efficiently categorize records in sub groups based on other values within the sub group?

Tags: sql, subquery, correlated-subquery

I have a table looks like below. The records are ordered by user_id and event_time.

```
Row    User_ID    Event_Time    Event_Type    
1      1          2020-01-01    View
2      1          2020-01-02    Click
3      1          2020-01-03    Purchase
4      2          2020-02-01    View
5      2          2020-02-02    Click
6      2          2020-02-03    View
7      2          2020-02-04    Purchase
8      2          2020-02-11    View
9      2          2020-02-12    Purchase
10     2          2020-02-21    View
11     2          2020-02-22    Click
12     2          2020-02-23    Purchase
13     2          2020-02-27    View
14     2          2020-02-28    Click
15     3          2020-03-01    View
16     3          2020-03-02    Purchase
...
```

I want to add a new column called Path to categorize non-purchase events. Each non-purchase event of a user "belongs" to the immediate purchase event **of the same user** that happened right after, meaning they can be viewed as a sub group. In each sub group:

- the first non-purchase event is **Introducer** (Row 1, 4, 10)
- the last non-purchase event is **Closer** (Row 2, 6, 11)
- all non-purchase event(s) between Introducer and Closer are **Influencer** (Row 5)
- if a purchase event only has one non-purchase event grouped with it, then the non-purchase event is **Only** (Row 8, 15)
- fill NULL in purchase events (Row 3, 7, 9, 12, 16)
- fill NULL if a non-purchase event doesn't belong to any purchase event (Row 13, 14)

So the table should look like this after adding the column:

```
Row    User_ID    Event_Time    Event_Type    Path
1      1          2020-01-01    View          Introducer
2      1          2020-01-02    Click         Closer
3      1          2020-01-03    Purchase      NULL
4      2          2020-02-01    View          Introducer
5      2          2020-02-02    Click         Influencer
6      2          2020-02-03    View          Closer
7      2          2020-02-04    Purchase      NULL
8      2          2020-02-11    View          Only
9      2          2020-02-12    Purchase      NULL
10     2          2020-02-21    View          Introducer
11     2          2020-02-22    Click         Closer
12     2          2020-02-23    Purchase      NULL
13     2          2020-02-27    View          NULL
14     2          2020-02-28    Click         NULL
15     3          2020-03-01    View          Only
16     3          2020-03-02    Purchase      NULL
...
```

The solution is easy if I do self-join and add a new column to help identify what time was the last purchase of a user for each event. However, I have over 100 million records and self-join is not efficient enough. The execution would eventually time out. So my question is, is there a more efficient way to add this new column? I'm thinking using correlated query but couldn't seem to wrap my head around it.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Please tag your question appropriately.

Comment: Sorry my bad! I'm running this in Google Bigquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This follows a similar approach to Nick, but I think the logic is simpler:

```
WITH e AS (
      SELECT e.*,
             SUM(CASE WHEN Event_Type = 'Purchase' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER
                 (PARTITION BY User_ID ORDER BY Event_Time DESC) AS grp
      FROM events e
     ),
     en as (
      SELECT e.*,
             COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, grp) as cnt,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, grp ORDER BY Event_Time) as seqnum
      FROM e
     )
SELECT en.*,
       (CASE WHEN grp = 0                   -- no purchase event
             THEN NULL 
             WHEN Event_Type = 'Purchase'   -- the event itself
             THEN NULL
             WHEN seqnum = 1 AND cnt = 2    -- the special case of "ONLY" 
             THEN 'Only'
             WHEN seqnum = 1                -- The first event
             THEN 'Introducer'
             WHEN seqnum = cnt - 1          -- The penultimate event
             THEN 'Closer'
             ELSE 'Influencer'
        END) as Path
FROM en
ORDER BY User_ID, Event_Time;
```

In particular, the subquery in the outer query is unnecessary.  The `grp = 0` finds the last group of events that may not have a purchase.  I also think it is easier to write the logic in terms of the total number of events and a sequential counter.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2c0ef152ea046c6dc54361c702f2983e) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks Gordon! This is easier to understand. I'll test it and see if this works!

Comment: It's so obvious when you see it written down, but sorting backwards just never occurred to me. It definitely makes this problem a *lot* easier.

Comment: @Nick . . . I went back and forth on whether or not to answer, because your version is reasonable.  In the end, the subquery tipped me into answering.

Comment: @GordonLinoff no one should have to suffer with a "reasonable" answer! :-) I'm sure losing the subquery will greatly improve the performance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a DBMS that supports window functions, you can use a couple of CTE's to first split the rows into different purchases, then find the row number relative to each of those purchases, and then finally compute the `Path` based on the conditions you have given:

```
WITH purchases AS (
  SELECT "Row", User_ID, Event_Time, Event_Type,
         COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN Event_Type = 'Purchase' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER
           (PARTITION BY User_ID ORDER BY Event_Time ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING), 0) AS pnum
  FROM events
),
prows AS (
  SELECT "Row", User_ID, Event_Time, Event_Type, pnum,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY User_ID, pnum ORDER BY Event_Time) AS rn,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY User_ID, pnum ORDER BY Event_Time DESC) AS drn
  FROM purchases
)
SELECT "Row", User_ID, Event_Time, Event_Type,
       CASE WHEN Event_Type = 'Purchase' OR
                 NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                             FROM prows r2 
                             WHERE r2.User_ID = r1.User_ID
                               AND r2.pnum = r1.pnum
                               AND r2.Event_Type = 'Purchase') THEN NULL
            WHEN rn = 1 AND drn = 2 THEN 'Only'
            WHEN rn = 1 THEN 'Introducer'
            WHEN drn = 2 THEN 'Closer'
            ELSE 'Influencer'
       END AS Path
FROM prows r1
ORDER BY User_ID, Event_Time
```

Output:

```
Row     User_ID     Event_Time  Event_Type  Path
1       1           2020-01-01  View        Introducer
2       1           2020-01-02  Click       Closer
3       1           2020-01-03  Purchase    (null)
4       2           2020-02-01  View        Introducer
5       2           2020-02-02  Click       Influencer
6       2           2020-02-03  View        Closer
7       2           2020-02-04  Purchase    (null)
8       2           2020-02-11  View        Only
9       2           2020-02-12  Purchase    (null)
10      2           2020-02-21  View        Introducer
11      2           2020-02-22  Click       Closer
12      2           2020-02-23  Purchase    (null)
13      2           2020-02-27  View        (null)
14      2           2020-02-28  Click       (null)
15      3           2020-03-01  View        Only
16      3           2020-03-02  Purchase    (null)
```

[SQL Server demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ba5e2/7). The same query will also run on PostgreSQL and Oracle.